# Attachinary Error on Heroku while it's working in local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, image-uploading, simple-form, cloudinary

I am trying to make a simple_form with an input for attachment so that when users are done with completing the forms, it sends me a mail through Postmark.

I have been setting up attachinary and everything works fine in localhost but as soon as I push it on Heroku, then it fails. I get a "We're sorry, but something went wrong" on the page where attachinary is called.

Heroku logs : [Screen of fatal errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo1Qd.png)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: hello. You need to include the output from your terminal of `heroku logs` right after triggering that message

Comment: Thks a lot for your message @FabrizioBertoglio, I've just updated my post

Comment: did you `bundle install` then added and commited your changes?

Comment: Yes I did, maybe it's an issue related to postmark accepting attaching files. Did you ever had to work on a similar case @FabrizioBertoglio. Maybe you made it in a different way ...

Comment: Ok, finally succeeded to solve the first error by adding to the gemfile the following block :
**git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end**

I have edited my post to show the last error I get, now I can deploy on heroku but I get a "we're sorry, but something went wrong". Thks for your help @FabrizioBertoglio